# How to access a global class instance?

Tags: c++, class, instance, global

I'm working on a program in C++ and so far I've tried to build it in layers.
So, so far I've got a class that handles all actions after the boot up such as clicks and keyboard controls and sits in the message loop etc and in that I've got several class instances that act as 'managers' such as Window manager and Debug Manager.

My question is, what's the best way to make certain ones of these 'Managers' available to access from everywhere?

for example, Math and Debug functions will need to be available from almost everywhere whilst I make my program.

What I've done so far is just pass a pointer to the manager down as I've created each class that needs to access it.
Is there a better way? And is this even a slightly okay way of doing it?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: ahh! forgot to mention that. I've edited it now. Its in C++

Comment: Can those functions be static?

Comment: @Kenney I tried this but as the debug manager will hold many variables that will constantly be changed I could not use static functions as they seemed to require the the variables to be const to access them.

Comment: You should read up on dependency injection - the cleanest way to do this in my opinion is to pass the managers into the constructors or methods that require them. That makes your code as readable as possible. I think you are on the right lines.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way?

In the days past, [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) were the suggested solution. Lately, [singletons have fallen out of favor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what).

In lieu of singletons, a set of functions under a suitable namespace is the next best method, IMO.

```
namespace WindowManager
{
   ...
}

namespace DebugManager
{
   ...
}
```

In the implementations of the functions in the respective namespaces, you can use a singleton as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

There are different design patterns you could use. Here are a few:

- **Factory Pattern**
  For example, you could call `LoggerFactory.getLogger( ... );` in each class that needs a Debug instance. The advantage is that you can get a different instance suited for the context in which it is called. For instance, you could pass a classname to use in logging.
- **Singleton Pattern**
  Similar to the factory pattern, except that `SomeFactory.getInstance()` will always returns the same instance. This is a good option if all the pointers you pass to the various classes are all for the same instance.
- **Global Variable**
  Similar to the singleton pattern, but much simpler. Often not advised.
- **Dependency Injection**
  This is basically the factory pattern, where class members get initialized using a service lookup (`ComponentRegistry.lookup(...)`). Done automatically by a container. Often used in languages that support method annotations.
- **Static methods** For utility functions, this is recommended. If they have a complex state (many variables), they should be kept in an instance. This instance can be a private static 'final' instance, hiding the internal state and offering a clean 'facade' to callers.

There are, of course, more.